# Overlay window is displayed off screen when running Selenium Test

Tags: selenium, jenkins, overlay

I have an issue when running a particular set of Selenium tests that act on an overlay window.  The issue is that the overlay window is not contained within the Firefox browser window when it is displayed (the left side of the overlay is cut off).

The weird thing is that when the tests are run locally using MbUnit via ReSharper in Visual Studio 2010, they pass just fine and the overlay never displays cut-off in the browser window (the browser window is not maximized during the test run).  However, when the test is run using MbUnit via Jenkins job the left side of the overlay gets cut off by the left side of the Firefox browser window (I tried attaching a screenshot, but as I am a new user here, I was prevented from doing so).

The reason why that's a problem is because there is an Upload button that needs to be clicked which is now not accessible due to it being off screen.  Here's the error when the test fails:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Element cannot be scrolled into view:[object HTMLDivElement]
Command duration or timeout: 56 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.24.1', revision: '17205', time: '2012-06-19 17:28:14'
System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_33'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

Two Questions:
1) Does anyone know why running the test via Jenkins would cause the overlay to display off screen?
2) Does anyone know how I can force the overlay to display within the browser window when the test runs?

Thank you kindly,
 . Adam .

Comment: Have you found solution for this which you would like to share? Or did any of the answers below worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same issue on Jenkins. I observed that the command ***browser.driver.manage.window.maximize*** only maximizes the window based on the screen size available. I believe the Jenkins default screen size is very small. So in order to over come the issue we have to specify the screen size manually.  You can solve the issue by adding the following in your code

```
browser.driver.manage.window.resize_to(1920, 1080)
    maximizeDim = browser.driver.manage.window.size
    puts "screenHeight after maximizing: #{+maximizeDim.height}"
    puts "screenWidth after maximizing: #{+maximizeDim.width}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I confront the exactly same problem. 
Solution:
Set fixed browser window size to fix this issue in Jenkins.

If you initialize the browser window size with driver.manage().window().maximize(), the maximal browser window size of some Jenkins servers may be much smaller than the one in your local computer. In that case, some elements(e.g button) displayed in the local computer's browser cannot display in Jenkins server's browser. It will make scripts locally passed fail in Jenkins. Initialize appropriate window size for testing